# cleaning a column of strings in a pandas dataframe with str comprehension

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe (df1) constructed from a survey in which participants entered their gender as a string and so there is a gender column that looks like:

```
id       gender       age
1        Male         19
2        F            22
3        male         20
4        Woman        32
5        female       26
6         Male        22
7        make         24
```

etc.

I've been using

```
df1.replace('male', 'Male')
```

for example, but this is really clunky and involves knowing the exact format of each response to fix it.

I've been trying to use various string comprehensions and string operations in Pandas, such as .split(), .replace(), and .capitalize(), with np.where() to try to get:

```
id       gender       age
1        Male         19
2        Female       22
3        Male         20
4        Female       32
5        Female       26
6        Male         22
7        Male         24
```

I'm sure there must be a way to use regex to do this but I can't seem to get the code right.

I know that it is probably a multi-step process of removing " ", then capitalising the entry, then replacing the capitalised values.

Any guidance would be much appreciated pythonistas!

Kev

Comment: You may need to know your data , then you can fix it

Comment: Removing what ""? In your example there are none.

Comment: Apologies, in row 6 the "Male" is preceded by a space, which is why it's out of line with the rest of the values. Sorry if I didn't make that clear enough.

Comment: You can do `df1["gender"] = df1.gender.apply(lambda s: s.strip().title()` to remove the spaces and capitalise. As Wen-Ben says you then need to know what values are possible to turn them into male/female

Comment: Thanks a million, @iuvbio. That helped a lot, once I've done that is it best to just use a

    df.replace()

on each of the options to replace each "bad" value with what I want?

Comment: @Wen-Ben Thanks for that, I had already explored the column to see what possible responses were in that column. I was struggling with coding a means to clean it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapt the code in my comment to replace every record that starts with an f with the word Female:

```py
df1["gender"] = df1.gender.apply(lambda s: re.sub(
                                    "(^F)([A-Za-z]+)*",  # pattern
                                    "Female",            # replace
                                    s.strip().title())   # string
                                )
```

Similarly for F with M in the pattern and replace with Male for Male.

Relevant [regex docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)
[Regex help](https://regexr.com)

Comment: Amazing answer, 

Thanks a whole million.